# Use of threads for controlling a serial port

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

A serial port is connected to a device that should shoot bytes continuously.
Speed is set to BaudRate 9600 with DataBits 8

So do some tests on the serial port: test: 1 ° door opening, 2nd receiving data, 3rd test on the received data
Since the device on the serial could not post anything I need a thread to make sure the program does not wait forever.

The code below seems to work, but not always in fact sometimes does not detect the door ...

```
 bool EsitoTest = false;

    private void rilevaPorta()
    {
        serialPorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        serialPort1.PortName = serialPorts[0];

        Thread mythreadTest = new Thread(() => testPortaSeriale(serialPort1)); // Lambda expression
        mythreadTest.Start();

        Thread th = Thread.CurrentThread;   // thread main
        Thread.Sleep(500);

        if (mythreadTest.IsAlive)
        {
             mythreadTest.Abort();
        }
        mythreadTest.Join();

        if (EsitoTest) if (!comboBoxSeriale.Items.Contains(comPort)) comboBoxSeriale.Items.Add(comPort);
    }

    private void testPortaSeriale(SerialPort sPort)
    {
        int[] buffer = new int[2];

        try
        {
            //  FIRST TEST - OPENING THE DOOR
            sPort.Open(); 
            testPS1 = true;
            serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();

            //  SECOND TEST  - RECEIVING DATA
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 2)
            {
                try
                {
                     while (sPort.BytesToRead < 1) ; // attendi finchè non c'è il nuovo dato
                     buffer[i] = sPort.ReadByte();
                     i++;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                     EsitoTest = false;
                }
                if (i == 2)
                {
                     testPS2 = true;

                    //  THIRD TEST (OPZIONAL)  - CONTROL VALUE DATA
                    if ((buffer[0] >= 0) & (buffer[0] <= 255) & (buffer[1] >= 0) & (buffer[1] <= 255))
                    {
                         testPS3 = true;
                         EsitoTest = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         EsitoTest = false;
                    }

               }
           }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             EsitoTest = false;
        }
        finally
        {
             sPort.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Calling DiscardInBuffer() is a serious threading race bug, you have no idea what you are discarding.  You have to delete that call.

Answer (score 0):

As a first reading some weaknesses :
1.You suppose you always have two chars. I suppose you know that and you control the source.
2.when you cut the thread (abort) you don't take care of the actual situation of the receipt : maybe you have receipt only one char at this very time. 
3.same thing : your code run once. What happens if nothing ? How long before you come back ? You can loose inputs.

You probably have better to leave the thread running for ever and use some kind of notifications.

Hth

Comment: In input every second I have lots of bytes, about 25. This should be just a test of the door, do not worry about the value of the data. Data acquisition will take place later.